# implement a function for holidays in a year?

Tags: php, datepicker

I have a list of holidays like:

```
var holiDays =[[2013,01,01,'New Years Day'],[2013-05-27, 'Memorial Day']]
```

and showing on the celender but this list is hard coded so i want a function in php so that all holidays list visible year wise.
`$(function() {
        $("#id_holiday_date").datepicker({ 
         beforeShowDay: setHoliDays
      });`

```
      // set holidays function which is configured in beforeShowDay
     function setHoliDays(date) {
       for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
         if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
              && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
              && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
            return [true, 'holiday', holiDays[i][3]];
         }
       }
      return [true, ''];
    }

 });
```

this function work properly in date picker.this date picker takes date from hardcoded array.

 
I want a function like that:


function calculateHolidays($year = '') {

```
$holiDays = Array();
$year = ($year != '') ? $year : date('Y'); //Default Current Year
$newYear = "$year-01-01";
$temp = "$year-05-00 last monday";
$memorialDay = strtotime($temp);//last Monday of May for Current Year
```

thanks in advance

Comment: So you want us to do your job for you? For free?

Comment: First make a function to display the calendar which is a basic for loop and make a string check (make the dates as keys, and check with in_array() )

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [PEAR date holidays](http://pear.php.net/package/Date_Holidays/) if I were you.

Comment: Curious package... They don't explain what "driver based holiday calculation" is but, at least in my country, holidays are decided and published by the government by the end of previous year. Only some days follow an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it - if you want to find all the brackets `[]` for a given year:

```
function display_holidays($year,$list){
    echo "<ul>";
    $list=str_replace(array('[[',']]','],['),array('[',']',']|['),$list);
    $list=explode("|",$list);
    foreach($list as $item){
        // find the items with the correct year
        if(strstr($item,"[".$year)){
            echo "<li>".$item."</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Usage example:

```
$list="[[2012,01,01,'New Years Day'],[2013,05,27, 'Memorial Day']]";
$year=2013;
display_holidays($year,$list);
```

the outcome will be:

```
<ul>
   <li>[2013,05,27, 'Memorial Day']</li>
</ul>
```

**ps**: but please explain in more detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to write a function like:function calculateHolidays($year = '') {
  
    $holiDays = Array();
    $year = ($year != '') ? $year : date('Y'); //Default Current Year
    $newYear = "$year-01-01";
    $temp = "$year-05-00 last monday";
    $memorialDay = strtotime($temp);//last Monday of May for Current Year

Comment: sorry I'm still confused, can you describe the desired output from this php function? And you have a long list of holidays for each year you want to work on inside this function?